# Unable to get static IP address to work with wlan0 (WiFi)

Tags: networking, wireless, static-ip

This is driving me crazy.  I can't seem to get a static IP address configured on my WiFi interface (wlan0).  I know that my `wpa_supplicant.conf` is correct because this same exact file works perfectly when I select `dhcp` instead of `static` on the `iface` statement.

The interface associates with my access point, but I get the error **network settings not defined for default in /etc/network/interfaces** in my syslog output (posted below).

#### `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    network 192.168.1.32
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.254
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

#### `syslog`

```
May 21 17:06:04 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[14738]: wlan0: Trying to associate with **:**:**:**:**:** (SSID='******' freq=2462 MHz)
May 21 17:06:04 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[14738]: wlan0: Association request to the driver failed
May 21 17:06:04 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[14738]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=**:**:**:**:**:** reason=0
May 21 17:06:04 raspberrypi wpa_action: WPA_IFACE=wlan0 WPA_ACTION=DISCONNECTED
May 21 17:06:04 raspberrypi wpa_action: WPA_ID=0 WPA_ID_STR= WPA_CTRL_DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
May 21 17:06:04 raspberrypi wpa_action: ifdown wlan0
May 21 17:06:05 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[14738]: wlan0: Trying to associate with **:**:**:**:**:** (SSID='******' freq=2462 MHz)
May 21 17:06:05 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[14738]: wlan0: Association request to the driver failed
May 21 17:06:05 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[14738]: wlan0: Associated with 00:00:00:00:00:00
May 21 17:06:05 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[14738]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=**:**:**:**:**:** reason=0
May 21 17:06:05 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[14738]: wlan0: Associated with **:**:**:**:**:**
May 21 17:06:05 raspberrypi wpa_action: removing sendsigs omission pidfile: /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid
May 21 17:06:06 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[14738]: wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with **:**:**:**:**:** [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
May 21 17:06:06 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[14738]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to **:**:**:**:**:** completed (reauth) [id=0 id_str=]
May 21 17:06:06 raspberrypi wpa_action: WPA_IFACE=wlan0 WPA_ACTION=CONNECTED
May 21 17:06:06 raspberrypi wpa_action: WPA_ID=0 WPA_ID_STR= WPA_CTRL_DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
May 21 17:06:06 raspberrypi wpa_action: network settings not defined for default in /etc/network/interfaces
May 21 17:06:06 raspberrypi wpa_action: ifup wlan0=default
May 21 17:06:06 raspberrypi wpa_action: creating sendsigs omission pidfile: /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid
May 21 17:06:06 raspberrypi wpa_action: bssid=**:**:**:**:**:**
May 21 17:06:06 raspberrypi wpa_action: ssid=******
May 21 17:06:06 raspberrypi wpa_action: id=0
May 21 17:06:06 raspberrypi wpa_action: mode=station
May 21 17:06:06 raspberrypi wpa_action: pairwise_cipher=CCMP
May 21 17:06:06 raspberrypi wpa_action: group_cipher=TKIP
May 21 17:06:06 raspberrypi wpa_action: key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
May 21 17:06:06 raspberrypi wpa_action: wpa_state=COMPLETED
May 21 17:06:06 raspberrypi wpa_action: address=**:**:**:**:**:**
May 21 17:06:07 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[14738]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 00:26:50:15:31:19 [GTK=TKIP]
May 21 17:06:08 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[14738]: wlan0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 00:26:50:15:31:19 [GTK=TKIP]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like you've actually defined an address in your `/etc/network/interfaces`. Try:

```
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.xxx
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.254
    dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

See the [Debian wiki article on network configuration](http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to tapped-out's answer, the network statement you have supplied is incorrect.
Either leave the network statement out altogether, or use the actual network address (in this example it would be 192.168.1.0)

Comment: Yes, my mistake was that I never intended to have a network statement.  I meant to say `address 192.168.1.32`, but put network instead.

Answer (score 0):

Where I just able to comment instead of answer submit...

ncdownpat & Hurgh both have answered your question well, however, the `dns-nameservers` line is also un-nessisary for inital connection setup; often I'll leave it off and have no issues connecting.

Here's the [link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/how-do-i-connect-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-hidden-network-with-no-passkey-using-a-stat/34440#34440) where I've gone to great detail already answering a similar question on StackExchange. Note I don't make use of the dns setting and I've also set the `iface` for `wlan0` to `manual` and then made a virtual `iface` with the same name as what is set for the `wpa_supplicant`'s `id_str` allowing for more than one access point to be added later. A single static IP was a bit boring so I've provided how to setup more than one internal static IP through the use of `post-up` & `pre-down` commands within the `interfaces` file. The bigest issue I've had with RPi's WiFi networking is that it'll die and not recover; so a scripted work around was also provided.